# Does $\sum_{n\ge1}x_n^n$ converge $\mathfrak m$-adically in $K[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]\ ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a field, let $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be indeterminates, and form the $K$-algebra  $A:=K[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$.

Recall that $A$ can be defined as the set of expressions of the form $\sum_ua_uu$, where $u$ runs over the set monomials in $x_1,x_2,\dots$, and each $a_u$ is in $K$, the multiplication being the obvious one.

The subset $\mathfrak m$ of $A$ defined by the condition $a_1=0$ is easily seen to be a maximal ideal.

> Does the series $\sum_{n\ge1}x_n^n$ converge $\mathfrak m$-adically in $A\ ?$

Three remarks:

(1) The series $\sum_{n\ge1}x_n^n$ is $\mathfrak m$-adically Cauchy.

(2) The condition that $\sum_{n\ge1}x_n^n$ converges $\mathfrak m$-adically is equivalent to the condition that, for all $n$, the element $\sum_{i\ge n}x_i^i$ of $A$ is in $\mathfrak m^n$. Sadly I'm unable to prove (or disprove) this condition even for $n=2$.

(3) Of course the underlying question is to know if $A$ is $\mathfrak m$-adically complete, and I would gladly accept an answer proving that $A$ is *not* $\mathfrak m$-adically complete, even if the convergence of $\sum_{n\ge1}x_n^n$ is not settled.

Comment: Does the expression $\sum_ix_i$ represent an element of your set? If so, I have difficulty apprehending the totality. If you had defined your set to be $\projlim_nK[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$, maybe I could get my failing brain around it, but this does not seem to be your intent.

Comment: @Lubin - Yes, $K[[x_1,x_2,\cdots]]$ can also been defined as $\projlim_nK[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$, and 
$\sum_ix_i$ does represent an element of this ring. I followed Bourbaki's phrasing. Note also that $K[[x_1,x_2,\cdots]]$ can be defined as a projective limit in various ways. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Hmm. Then presumably $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence with limit zero, but not $(x)$-adically convergent?

Comment: @Lubin - Thanks for your comment. Just to make sure: did you notice that the series in the question is $\sum_nx_n^n$, not $\sum_nx_n$? This being said, I agree with what you wrote. But it seems clear to me that the sequence $(x_n^n)$ tends to $0$ in both topologies.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly was aware of that, but I used this case to help me understand which ring you were considering. I just think that in dealing with $\infty$ly many indeterminates, we need to be extremely careful and scrupulous.

Comment: Now also posted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308251/is-kx-1-x-2-dots-an-mathfrak-m-adically-complete-ring